# Grails plugin dependency pulled into maven cache, but main project can't resolve classes

Tags: grails, maven-2

Using Grails 2.5.4

- I have a plugin that uses the Twilio SDK (7+).
- The plugin packages without error.
- When I run the main project it throws an error saying that the it
  cannot resolve the *import com.twilio.Twilio* class in the plugin
  controllers/services.
- I confirm that the Twilio SDK has been pulled into the local Maven
  cache when the plugin was pulled in, so it knows to get the dependency.
- The main project BuildConfig includes mavenLocal() in the dependency 
  resolution.

Where do I look next to find the cause of this dependency resolution problem?

plugin dependencies.groovy

```
grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven"
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
// inherit Grails' default dependencies
inherits("global") {
    // excludes 'ehcache'
}
log "warn" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility
repositories {
    grailsCentral()
    // uncomment the below to enable remote dependency resolution
    // from public Maven repositories
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()

}
dependencies {
      compile 'com.twilio.sdk:twilio:7.8.0' 
 }
```

in plugin.xml

```
<dependencies>
   <compile>
     <dependency group='com.twilio.sdk' name='twilio' version='7.8.0' />
   </compile>
</dependencies>
```

In main project BuildConfig.gorrcy

```
 plugins{
     compile ":twilio-ext:1.0"
 }
```

running grails dependency-report I see

```
  org.grails.plugins:twilio-ext:1.0
```

But it has no sub dependencies listed.

Comment: What do you see when running `grails dependency-report runtime` ?

Comment: Also, it's interesting to add which grails version you're using.

Comment: using grails 2.5.4. Hmm, I don't see it in the runtime dependencies...so the main project doesn't know it needs it. How do I propagate depencies?

Comment: You could try `grails refresh-dependencies`